# How to remove first character of a string if it is a number using jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which is a persons address. 
I do not want to include the person house/building number so am doing

```
address.replace(/\d+/, '')
```

This removes the first set of numbers from the address. If the address doesn't include a house number it will remove the areacode/postal code which I do not want.

How do I only remove the firs number from the string if the string begins with a number?

Thanks

Comment: Using jQuery? ... you can do this with plain JavaScript... you should edit your title, otherwise its misleading

Answer (score 1):

You can use the beginning of string notation(`^`)

```
address.replace(/^\d+/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` in the [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to remove the numbers if the `address` starts with number. You might also want to `trim` the string first to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
address.trim().replace(/^\d+/, '');
//                      ^
```

**Visualization**

[image]

**Example:**

```js
var address = '    252 some thins, something, something, 14245    ';
address = address.trim().replace(/^\d+/, '');

alert(address);
```

This will remove the numbers, if address starts with number.